# Groovy/grails: pass parameter to thread

Tags: multithreading, grails, groovy

In a grails controller a new thread (task / Promise) is started. But the user is null when i try to get it within the thread.

```
if(springSecurityService.currentUser){
                task {
                    // do something with the current user
                    // springSecurityService.currentUser is null here!!!!!!
                }.get()
            }
```

How can i pass the user as a parameter to the task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't so much that "the thread is started after the controller has been left by the user" but rather that `springSecurityService.currentUser` is thread-local state that gives you different values when called from different threads.  But if you save *this thread's value* of `springSecurityService.currentUser` in a local variable you should be able to access that inside the closure:

```
if(springSecurityService.currentUser){
   def theUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
   task {
       // do something with theUser
   }.get()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But how can i pass arguments to the thread in general?

Comment: @elCapitano the closure will have access to all the fields of the controller class or in-scope local variables of the containing action so you shouldn't need to "pass arguments" as such, you just have to watch out for properties that hide thread-local state, such as `params`, `request` and `response` - anything that might be thread-local you will have to save in a local variable before entering the closure.

Comment: Is this thread-safe? For example, is it safe to pass a non-thread-safe List object to multiple Promises that are executing in parallel to add items to the list? If not, how should that be approached?